# Magento 2: How to override event "checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after"

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I want to override an event `checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after`.
For this I already tried below code :

**etc/frontend/events.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
     <event name="checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after">
        <observer name="mycustomobserver" instance="Namespace\Module\Observer\CreateTestFormObserver"/>
     </event>
</config>
```

**Namespace\Module\Observer\CreateTestFormObserver.php**

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;

class CreateTestFormObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
  private $logger;
  protected $messageManager;

   public function __construct(
     \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
   }
   public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
   {
       $this->logger->addDebug('CreateTestFormObserver');
   }
}
```

But my file is not called after placing an order. I identify this by my log, which is not generated on or after placing an order.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution which is as below :

Change event.xml file position to etc/events.xml and code is :

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after">
       <observer name="mycustomobserver" instance="Namespace\Module\Observer\Frontend\CreateTestForm"/>
   </event>
</config>
```

And put folder of event at Namespace\Module\Observer\Frontend\CreateTestForm.php  and now code is :

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Observer\Frontend;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;

class CreateTestForm implements ObserverInterface
{
    private $logger;
    protected $messageManager;

    public function __construct(
     \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger) {
    $this->logger = $logger;
  }
  public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
  {
    $this->logger->addDebug('CreateTestFormObserver');
  }
}
```

Comment: I think also you have to change 'checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after' event because of it is not working on place order. please check it after cler cache if working then inform to me. i have already try but not sucess with this event.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using event **`checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`**,

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
     <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="mycustomobserver" instance="Namespace\Module\Observer\CreateTestFormObserver"/>
     </event>
</config>
```

For using above event, you can debug your code and its same as your event.

Basically checkout event flow for place order is display below,

```
checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method

sales_order_place_after

checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after

checkout_onepage_controller_success_action
```

So change event and try again using remove var folder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

create events.xml in etc/ insted of etc/frontend/events.xml

and add below code to event.xml

```
<event name="sales_order_save_commit_after">
     <observer name="my_test_observer" instance="Namespace\Module\Observer\CreateTestFormObserver" />
</event>
```

let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: Im facing similar issue. unable to proceed to checkout onepage success ....could you please help here..http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127408/sales-order-payment-place-end-error-in-checkout-page-on-click-of-place-my-order